# How to install the React Native Expo App in iOS?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have successfully created iOS build of React Native Expo App and I also downloaded it to the iPhone. But I am not able to install it in the phone. I am not able to open the file. 
Please help if anyone has any idea regarding this.[image: This is image I have uploaded. This is what i am getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can install your React-native Expo app on your iOS device if you have an Apple developer account, you can follow the detailed step-by-step guide in this article:
https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/your-guide-to-testing-your-expo-react-native-application-on-ios-abbde4086d08

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly install the React-native Expo app on your phone. You must use the AppStore or Expo client for IOS.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/distribution/app-stores/

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/